# when i use my emacs with purcell's .emacs.d ,i can't use slime

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

when i try M-x slime ,all i get is

Can't locate module: SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::SWANK-TRACE-DIALOG

but when i use my own .emacs.d ,it works.

how can i fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the same issue, I have solved it.

The reason is that I installed slime with "sudo apt-get install slime" before, I guess this package will mess up with locally installed(by init.el when emacs first start) in ~/.emacs.d/elpha/slime-2*.

Solution: Check that if you have slime in /usr/lib/emacs/site-lisp,or something like that. If you do have this package, remove this system level slime with:

```
sudo apt-get remove slime
```

Restart emacs after this, and emacs should be able to use right slime package, problem should disappear after this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as you did. I got an error that's something like "couldn't find package Emacs-24.4". This inspired me to install `Emacs-24.4` on my Ubuntu, instead of older version `24.3` which is the newest I can get from `apt-get`. (A convincing fact is that the newer version `24.5` provided by `Homebrew` works well with Purcell's package on my Mac.)

Under `Emacs 24.4`, `slime` proved to run well with Purcell's `.emacs.d/`. But it really costs me a lot of time to install `Emacs-24.4` on my Ubuntu. First, I had to solve the problems of dependencies. Using `aptitude`, I get rid of the problem which `apt-get` failed to solve:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install build-essential
sudo aptitude build-dep emacs24
```

When the dependency issue pops out, `aptitude` will give you some suggestions including downgrading your current packages. I chose solutions of downgrade without leaving over any unsolved dependency problem (select 'no' until you find an acceptable one). During reinstalling build packages, Ubuntu iso cdrom may be required.

Then install `Emacs 24.4`:

```
wget http://open-source-box.org/emacs/emacs-24.4.tar.xz
tar xvf emacs-24.4.tar.xz
cd emacs-24.4
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/.local/lib --without-pop --without-kerberos --without-mmdf --without-sound --without-wide-int --without-xpm --without-jpeg --without-tiff --without-gif --without-png --without-rsvg --without-xml2 --without-imagemagick --without-xft --without-libotf --without-m17n-flt --without-xaw3d --without-xim --without-ns --without-gpm --without-dbus --without-gconf --without-gsettings --without-selinux --without-gnutls --without-x
make && make install
```

References:

https://gist.github.com/tnarihi/6054dfa7b4ad2564819b

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-emacs-24-4-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/